# Android: Animations - how to determine the end of an xml file animation and start an AlphaAnim in java?

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I have an animation(xml) file that sets an image view to appear like the credits of a movie:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >

<translate
    android:duration="10000"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />

</set>
```

As you can see, the image stops "moving" when it gets full screen. This is ok.
My question is: how can I set a textView (hidden) visible when this IV reaches de end of the animation, so the text can be over the image?

The java code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_final);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    mozart=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mozart);

      Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.amadeus).fit().centerCrop().into(mozart);

    read=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.read);
    restart=(Button) findViewById(R.id.restart);
    restart.setOnClickListener(this);

    Animation moz= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);
    mozart.startAnimation(moz);

    read.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    read.setText("Text to appear with other alphaAnimation");

}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == restart) {
        allaTurca.stop();

       Intent a = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(a);
        this.finish();
    }

  }

}
```

Is it possible? I've tried several aproaches, but I cant't figure out how to tell the program when the image is ready to "receive" the text. Thaks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FOR ANIMATION START REPEAT AND END**

You have to add an animation listener to the animation like this

```
moz.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
   //Do Something on start
}           
@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
}           
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
}
});
```

When the animation starts it will first pass through the onStart( this is where u can initialize variables for animation) ...

then if you have repetition in your animation onAnimationRepeat will be called.

When the Animation is finished the onAnimationEnd will be called. **( This is the part you are interested in)**

**EDIT**
As pointed out in the comments ... the better way of doing this is using AnimatorListenerAdapter .... thank you marmor

```
AnimatorListenerAdapter onEnd = new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator _a) {
            DropZone.this.setTranslationY(getHeight() + 2);
            DropZone.this.setAlpha(0f);
        }
    };
```

You can find examples here http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter

Comment: FYI, for simpler, more readable code you can use `AnimatorListenerAdapter` allowing to override only needed methods (in this case only onAnimationEnd)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorListenerAdapter.html